# Hibernate Mapping Understanding

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, mapping

i have a little problem by understanding how hibernate maps collection bidiractional.

Wanted is the following:
Tables schema:

event (e_id,date, i_id)

info (i_id, detailDesc)

i have multiple events and some info objects which sums ups details to x events. As objects i have different Event Objects and some Info objects which should contains a list of event objects. The Event Objects which are related to Info Object should have a info object assoziated, see the class info below.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "info")
public class Info {
    @Id
    @GenericGenerator(name = "gen", strategy = "increment")
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "gen")
    @Column(name = "i_id")
    private long id;

    @JoinTable(name = "events",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "e_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "i_id"))
    @OneToMany(targetEntity = Event.class, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<Event> events;

    String detailDesc;

}


@Entity
    @Table(name = "event") 
    public class Event {
        @Id
        @GenericGenerator(name = "gen", strategy = "increment")
        @GeneratedValue(generator = "gen")
        @Column(name = "e_id")
        private long id;

        // Can be NULL 
        @ManyToOne(targetEntity = Info.class, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, optional = true)
        @JoinColumn(name = "i_id")
        private Info info;

       private Date date;

    }
```

as it is now, hibernate says duplicate entry or foreign key constraint fails (`event`, CONSTRAINT `FK_r9sdjn6nelyo5be86vu0b2prs` FOREIGN KEY (`e_id`) REFERENCES `info` (`i_id`))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your mappings are incorrect. Given your schema, you are not using a JoinTable so therefore set the @JoinColumn on the @ManyToOne side (as you have) and simply use 'mappedBy' on the inverse side. Ensure both sides of the relationship are set to ensure cascading works as expected.

If you did want to use a join table (rather than a FK  from event > info) then you would move your existing @JoinTable to the @ManyToOne and remove the @JoinColumn. The inverse side would remain as below regardless of whether you used @JoinTable or @JoinColumn.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "info")
public class Info {

    @Id
    @GenericGenerator(name = "gen", strategy = "increment")
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "gen")
    @Column(name = "i_id")
    private long id;


    @OneToMany(mappedBy="info" cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Event> events;

    String detailDesc;

    //set both sides of the relationship
    public void addEvent(Event event){
        event.setInfo(this);
        events.add(event);
    }

    public List<Event> getEvents(){
        //return unmodifiable list or iterator to force clients through addEvent() method
    }

}


@Entity
@Table(name = "event") 
 public class Event {
    @Id
    @GenericGenerator(name = "gen", strategy = "increment")
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "gen")
    @Column(name = "e_id")
    private long id;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, optional = true)
    @JoinColumn(name = "i_id")
    private Info info;

   private Date date;

 }
```